# Modify code to make it a Navigational based application

Tags: cordova, sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I have used the [following tutorial for my project](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/guide/getting_started). I need to add a button, and when the user clicks on that button. i need it to navigate to another vire, but it should be added to the Navigation stack (so it will have a back button by default).

**In a nutshell, what i require is to [modify the code of this tutorial](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/guide/getting_started) to make it a Navigation based application.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is [`Ext.navigation.View`](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-0/#!/api/Ext.navigation.View)

Try this simple code from the above link ..

```
var view = Ext.create('Ext.NavigationView', {
    fullscreen: true,

    items: [{
        title: 'First',
        items: [{
            xtype: 'button',
            text: 'Push a new view!',
            handler: function() {
                //use the push() method to push another view. It works much like
                //add() or setActiveItem(). it accepts a view instance, or you can give it
                //a view config.
                view.push({
                    title: 'Second',
                    html: 'Second view!'
                });
            }
        }]
    }]
});
```

Comment: Yes, i tried this, and it works. but i want to navigate to another view from my Controller class. `push` doesn't work there for some reason. :(

Comment: In that case, you can give your `navigationview` some `id` and then inside the handler function, you can write something like this ... `Ext.getCmp('navigate-id').push({ ...`

Comment: You mean to specify a `id` on the Main.js and call it from the controller class ?